# NSURLConnection synchronous problem

Tags: objective-c

I am writing an iPhone app which will call a webservice method by using soap message format.
I need a synchronous process because table view needs those data before it can be displayed.
So I use [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]

The problem is, the whole program will exit without any error message after the method call.
Even I put a NSLog statement just after the 
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:],
there is no any output so I am sure the program exit during that method call. Actually during
that HTTP request and response stuff.

However, if I set a breakpoint before that method call, and run the program in debug mode, 
everything runs well, the program will not exit, and I got my results as well.

Can anyone figure out what is going on?
Thanks.

```
- (void) sendSyncHTTPRequest:(NSString *)request_data operation:(ServOperationSync *)serv_ops { 
id<ServiceData> serv_data = serv_ops.dataDelegate;
NSURL *urlAddr = [NSURL URLWithString:[serv_data getServURL]];

urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:urlAddr
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                 timeoutInterval:90];
NSData *requestData = [request_data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[urlRequest setValue:@"MobilePortal" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[urlRequest setValue:[serv_data getSoapAction] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[urlRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", [requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[urlRequest setValue:urlAddr.host forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:requestData];

NSLog(@"just before sending http request");
[serv_ops.responseData setData:[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlRequest returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&urlError]];
NSLog(@"after sending http request");
```

}

Note that urlResponse and urlError are declared as instance variables.

Comment: I have more information about it.
When I run the program, and I press the "Pause" from the console tool bar, and resume
the program, all things are good, I get the result.
If I run the program, do nothing and let it run, the program exit without any messages.

So it seems like the program can not run in its own process or thread, run loop or what.
I am not sure, because I think no matter if I run the program in debug mode or pause
it then resume, actually I attach the program process to other or what, like hooked by
GDB?

Any information will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that NSURLConnection is the reason for your crash?!

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide us enough code to find out why your app doesn't behave correctly.

Using `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:]` is generally a bad idea, because it blocks the current thread. You are probably calling it from the main thread, this will block the UI. The app won't respond to touches and feels like frozen, when the request takes long (especially on low bandwidth connection like EDGE).

The nature of networking is asynchronous. So I'd advise you to make an asynchronous request instead or use [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html). Update the Tableview in delegate methods (connection:didReceiveData: etc.). You may save the tableview data in an `NSMutableArray` and call [`tableView reloadData]` after modifying the array. The tableview would then be constructed from that array in the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate methods.

Comment: I am sure is [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:] cause the problem. This is because I put a NSLog just before it and just after it, the former one can be displayed and the latter one won't display the message. Actually I need to use this synchronous because it is when the app is startup, I call it in the applicationDidFinishLaunching method, I need those data to populate the first view in my app which is a table view. If I use asynchronous way, the window will appear right away and the blank navigation view and table view will be displayed which is not good.

Answer (score 0):

You need:

- a run loop on your code
- and don't forget your NSURLConnection
  delegates

Comment: Hi, Neilvert, thanks for you reply. Are you saying I need to use asynchronous because synchronous does not provide a delegate parameter. I just wonder how to use asynchronous to achieve what I want, that is to prevent the blank table view to pop up. I think I still need to block the thread in some way, and isn't this just what synchronous doing?